# How can I add screenshots of programs to the Software Center

Tags: software-center

Some programs in the Software Center lack screenshots. Is there a way to add them?

Idea: It would be nice if there was some sort of button *Add Screenshot* under the "no screenshot" area

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can quickly and easily [add screenshots](http://screenshots.debian.net/upload) to [screenshots.debian.net](http://screenshots.debian.net/upload) which is the website that the Software Centre gets its screenshots from.

There will be a delay in your uploads appearing in the Software Centre, because all screenshots are first moderated.

Comment: I guess this only applies to programs being released in debian, what about programs only released in Ubuntu?

Comment: @Pit it does apply to Ubuntu programs also (see [this list of repositories that it includes](http://screenshots.debian.net/about))

Comment: i'm trying to add the Snes9x's screenshot but it seems there is no package Snes9x in Debian so i can't add the screenshot, however Snes9x exists in USC.

Comment: @user8972 snes9x [is in Debian](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=snes9x). I suspect the reason you can't add a screenshot for it is because the program is not fully open source. This might be by design, but you could [report a bug](http://debshots.workaround.org/trac/).

Comment: More likely you are not able to upload a screenshot because the package is no longer present in new versions of debian: it was removed because it was no longer maintained. http://packages.qa.debian.org/s/snes9x/news/20110314T095707Z.html

Answer (score 5):

You can upload the screenshots.

- [Browsing for packages without screenshots](http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/packages?show=without)
- [Uploading](http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/upload)

Comment: [screenshots.ubuntu.com](http://screenshots.ubuntu.com) seems an exact mirror of  [screenshots.debian.net](https://screenshots.debian.net). They resolve to different IPs, though.