# How to include a screenshot of my application in the DEB/PPA to show it in Software-Center?

Tags: software-center, ppa

I know how to create a DEB and push it into my PPA at Launchpad but I want to know how I can include a screenshot of the application that it shows up in Software-Center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your application to have a screenshot in the software-center, it has to be in the repositories.

If you are interested in getting your package into the repositories, follow this question.

- [How-To add a software to the ubuntu software-center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91296/how-to-add-a-software-to-the-ubuntu-software-center)

Once you have the package into the repository, you can follow this question to add the screenshot for your package.

- [How can I add screenshots of programs to the Software Center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24593/how-can-i-add-screenshots-of-programs-to-the-software-center/24595#24595)

Answer (score 5):

The Software Center pulls screenshots out based on package name from a central screenshot server, so it's the same as any other package, you upload images through the Ubuntu Screenshots site:

- http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/upload

**However** that site will only let you enter in package names that already exist in the main repos. If you're developing a new package, you're going to be screenshot-less until you're in the main repos.