# How to add icon and screenshot for my app .deb package to see it in Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, icons, packaging

I created a .deb package of application by myself and I want to add to it icon and screenshot to visualize it in Application Manager such as Ubuntu Software Center. When I launch my package by double-click. For example, when I launch virtualbox or skype packages their icon and  screenshot appear. How can I make this? Is it possible?

Comment: Have you checked out the .desktop file for each of them? It may be that they pint to the files with the screenshot, if who just copy the format and modify it to your requirements.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you actually mean. How can the .desktop file help me in this case? Could you explain in details please?

Comment: You can use the desktop file to point to an app icon, and I suspect also a screenshot. Check this thread for more info http://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two questions here, the first is about the icon; this is actually provided by the app data package which has a pre-set number of defined icons. You can find it in:

```
/usr/share/app-install/icons/
```

But it won't help you put an icon in the software center. No custom packages have icons in the software center.

The second is about the screenshot. These can be added here:

[How to include a screenshot of my application in the DEB/PPA to show it in Software-Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117130/how-to-include-a-screenshot-of-my-application-in-the-deb-ppa-to-show-it-in-softw)

Comment: Can I make this without pushing my application into PPA at Launchpad?
I distribute my .deb packages by making archive and placing link to it on my web site. Then user can download the archive and get .deb package in it. When user launch my package the app icon and screenshot should appear in package manager. 
By the way I can add some info about my app (such as name, version and description ) into package control file. I need something like this.

Comment: There is no way to get the icon there. You can add a screenshot by adding the image to the above link. Other values such as name, descriptions and versions are all held in the deb package. Please see deb package creation guides for further help.